# CSS Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to give margin-top:10px to id download-csv

Here is     html and javascrpit:

```
<span style="display: inline;"  id="download-csv"><input type="submit"   id="csv_download"  value="Download"></span>;



JavaScript :
         var download_csv=document.getElementById("download-csv");
if(count_layer==1)
        download_csv.setAttribute("style","margin-top:10px");
}else{
       download_csv.setAttribute("style","margin-top:20px");

}
```

Its throws error
  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
if(count_layer==1)
        download_csv.style.marginTop = "10px";
}else{
       download_csv.style.marginTop = "20px";
}
```

Comment: sorry to write double time style.style it is the only style one style try this again, please.

Comment: Sir i wrote this one but Same error        download_csv.style.marginTop = "10px";

Comment: Welll  Thanks Sir

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure that markup is loaded before those elements are accessed by the JS code.

Also, you cannot give `margin`s to `inline` elements, set `display` *style property* as `display-inline`.

```js
var download_csv = document.getElementById("download-csv");
var count_layer = 1;
if (count_layer == 1) {
  download_csv.style.marginTop = "10px";
} else {
  download_csv.style.marginTop = "50px";
}
```

```html
<span style="display: inline-block;" id="download-csv">
   <input type="submit"   id="csv_download"  value="Download">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now your javascript code is being executed before the page loads, thus the `<html>`attribute won't be loaded yet, and then you will get the error.

To fix it, put your javascript code inside $(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Your code goes here
}) ;
```

Comment: Not sure if this guy is using jquery

Comment: Mostly JavaScript